# How would you write a line of code in a specific file on your computer to alias a remote server?

Tags: networking

I'm trying to create an alias for an IP to make the name easier to remember. I don't want to change the name because there are already things synced to it.

Answer (score 2):

Setup another DNS entry and point it to the same IP. If you can't make a DNS entry, you can add it to your local hosts file.

Example:

```
192.168.1.50      OriginalAlias.yourdomain.com
192.168.1.50      NewAlias.yourdomain.com
```